# Video streaming app doesn't work at GCP, but works at local PC

Tags: firewall, google-compute-engine

I am working on a VM and installing everything I require between them ROS and Flask, I used a code from https://github.com/emmanuel-senft/flask-ros.git, I tested it on my personal PC with linux and It works, you can see the streaming video at the localhost address. I run it on the VM, I go to the external IP address and it doesn't work. I have http, https enabled. I hope you can help me, I have been doing it for 1 week and I am not able to use my google VM well.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Please ask your question in english.

Comment: My English is regular:

Comment: I am working on a VM and installing everything I require between them ROS and Flask, I used a code from https://github.com/emmanuel-senft/flask-ros.git, I tested it on my personal PC with linux and It works, you can see the streaming video at the localhost address. I run it on the VM, I go to the external IP address and it doesn't work. I have http, https enabled. 
I hope you can help me, I have been doing it for 1 week and I am not able to use my google VM well.

regards

Comment: That's better, but we still can't help you with it. Please edit your question and add every relevant configuration you have, along with commands you used for your tests and actual error messages you got. Vague descriptions are not helpful in diagnosing problems.

Comment: I understand. Can I save a video and show the process?

Comment: If there is no other way ... configuration files and errors in text form are preferable though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on your local Linux machine at `localhost` address because it's not affected by your firewall. As you can see at the [documentation](https://github.com/emmanuel-senft/flask-ros):

> **Usage**:
>
> ```
> roslaunch video_stream_opencv camera.launch video_stream_provider:=*x*' gunicorn --threads 5 --workers 1 --bind your_ip:8080 app:app'
> ```
>
> - Replace `x` by the number of the video feed to open `/dev/videox`.
> - Replace `your_ip` by the machine's ip.

This application works at port `8080` which is blocked by GCP firewall by default.

**To solve this issue** you should open port 8080 on firewall:

1. [set network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#adding_new_tags_to_vm_instances) on your VM by following
2. [create new firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) that open allow port towards your network tag

> If you want the rule to apply to select instances by network (target)
>   tags, choose Specified target tags, then type the tags to which the
>   rule should apply into the Target tags field.

3. as machine's IP for command use *internal* IP
4. go to `EXTERANAL_IP_OF_YOUR_VM:8080` to check streaming service

Comment: Thanks Serhii Rohoza, I did this: 
To solve this issue you should open port 8080 on firewall:

set network tag on your VM by following
create new firewall rule that open allow port towards your network tag.

I modified the code in line: frame = cv2.imencode(".jpg",img_np)[1].tobytes() 
for this 
frame = cv2.imencode(".jpg",img_np)[1].tostring()

and nowm this ok.

I run command:

rosrun package app.py, not roslaunch